# Configure App Service on Azure with .NET Core

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-appservice

I am trying to fully automate the creation of our AppServices using the RM Powershell from Azure. I'm trying to work out how to get the appservice to run using .NetCore instead of .NetFramework. The default Runtime Stack is .NET, with ASP.NET version 4.7 on it.

I've looked through the Powershell Samples but can't find anything that changes to using .netcore.

How does the runtime stack get updated to .NET Core if i dont want to do it manually? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the Runtime stack to .Net Core with the `CURRENT_STACK` property:

```
$PropertiesObject = @{
    "CURRENT_STACK" = "dotnetcore"
}

New-AzureRmResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName "<resource-group-name>" -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName "MyContosoWebSite/metadata" -ApiVersion 2018-02-01 -Force
```

The output would be similar to:
[image: WebApp Properties]

You can then verify the change from the Azure portal as well:

[image: Azure Portal]